# Determine the smallest $k$ such that $\log (1 +e^x) < k + x ?$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Determine the  smallest  $k$ such that  $\log (1  +e^x)  < k  + x  $  where $k$ is constant and $x \in (0,\infty)$

My attempt :$$\log(1+e^x)= e^x -\frac{e^{x}}{2}  +\frac{e^{2x}}{3}+.....$$
$$e^x  = 1 +x+x^2/2^2+...$$
$$\log(1+e^x)= (1+x+x^2/2^2+....)-\frac{1}{2}(1+x+x^2/2^2+...)\\+\frac{1}{3}(1+2x+(2x)^2/2^2+...)-\frac{1}{4}(1+3x+(3x)^2/2^2+...$$
$$=(1-\frac{1}{2}  +\frac{1}{3} -\frac{1}{4}+...)  + x(1-1/2+2/3-3/4+....)  +  \text{higher degree} $$

$$\implies\log(1+e^x)   < \log 2  + x \implies  k=\log 2$$

Comment: I think you should show that all higher degree coefficients are nonnegative, including the $x$ coefficient.

Comment: Just simply show that $\log(1+e^x)-x$ is strictly decreasing for $x>0$. It is straightforward using the derivative.

Comment: Also, the series of $\log (1+w)$ is valid only for $|w|<1$, so you cannot apply it with $w=e^x$ when $x>0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your final answer is correct, though the way you obtained is not, as was explained in the comments.

We simply find $\sup_{x\in(0,\infty)}\log(1+e^x)-x$. Note that
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\log(1+e^x)-x\right]=\frac{e^x}{1+e^x}-1=-\frac{1}{1+e^x}<0$$
for all $x\in(0,\infty)$. Therefore, $x\mapsto \log(1+e^x)-x$ is strictly decreasing on $(0,\infty)$ and
$$k:=\sup_{x\in(0,\infty)}\log(1+e^x)-x=\log(1+e^0)-0=\log 2.$$
(Note that if the domain were $[0,\infty)$ such a constant $k$ would not exist.)

Comment: The OP's solution is incorrect for the reasons we pointed out in the comments.

Comment: @Gary Yeah, but his final answer is. I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: Also, you have to look at the $\sup$ and not the $\inf$.

Comment: @user2661923 The problem is that one has to look at the $\sup$ and not the $\inf$ if you think about it. Your argument is also invalid in general: $g(x)/f(x) \to 1$ does not imply $g(x)-f(x)\to 0$.

Comment: You are right, I read the problem too quickly.  So, when $x = 0$, you have that $f(x) = \log(2).$

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=e^x (e^k -1)>1$ is strictly increasing.
$\\ $ $f(x\to +0)>1 \implies k>\ln 2 $ or $\inf k =\ln 2 $.